# Setting Intent for AlarmManager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, alarmmanager

To be able to create an alarm manager implementation, you have to use an intent and a pending intent, according to all the references I saw, however I get these errors, and I'm not sure why because my code is almost identical to others.

There are 2 errors. This is the code with the 2 errors for both Intent and PendingIntent:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Content;
using Android.App;

namespace Assignment {
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ChooseAlarm : ContentPage {
    public ChooseAlarm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var donebutton = this.FindByName<Button>("doneButton");

        donebutton.Clicked += donebutton_Clicked;
    }

    private void donebutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        StartAlarm();
    }
    private void StartAlarm() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmNotificationReceiver)); --Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'Java.Lang.Class'

        PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0); --Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Assignment.ChooseAlarm' to 'Android.Content.Context', same for above

        manager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Android.OS.SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 4000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Receiver code, no errors:

```
using Assignment.Droid;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Android;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.App;

namespace Assignment {
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        builder.SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentTitle("Alarm Actived!")
            .SetContentText("test")
            .SetContentInfo("Info");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I put them in the code after the "--", should have made it more obvious

Comment: From my experience if you post only the most relevant code and description of your problem you'll get a better answer and faster. This is because people usually will not spend time on long posts. This is explained better in [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should have activity, Which inherits `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
```

& here your current class should be activity. Than you keyword `this` going to work.

```
PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

What I realize that you are using Android code in Xamarin forms shared project which is not going to work. You need to have Xamarin.forms code there. Otherwise use it in Android project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So I need to call a the StartAlarm method in MainActivity? The errors go away but when I'm trying to call it from an xamarin forms class, it does this: https://ibb.co/kwLQNp For this to work, I need to send the intent from the android's MainActivity?

Comment: You can't call it forms shared project. Call it in mailActvitiy only however your activity has already been started.

Comment: How would I tell MainActivity to call the StartAlarm, after e.g. user clicks on button?

Comment: To do so you need to use custom renderer or DependencyService do some research. If I find any way I would help you.